# How can I fix operator problem in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void протабулюватиToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[] mas = new double[100];
        double y, x, h, b;
        int i = 0;
       b = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
        h = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        for ( x ; x <= b; x += h)
        {
            y = (1440 * Math.Pow(x, 2) - 3200 * x);
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(x + "\t" + y);
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\\Temp\\file1.txt", y + "\t" +
               x + "\r\n");

            }
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                mas[i] = y;
                i++;
            }

        }

    }
```

When I try to run the program, it writes to me "Only expressions of assignment, call, etc. can be used as an operator." X is underlined in red where `for ( x ; x <= b; x += h)`

Comment: So remove the underlined `x`? It's unclear why you put it there since it doesn't do anything

Comment: `for ( double x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text); x <= b; x += h) {...}` while removing all `x` above the `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write any expression into first part of `for()`.

Your code can look like `for(;x <= b; x += h)`.

For more reference look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for